# jQuery fullcalendar: How can I target and change the background color of the days that don't belong to the current month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm building a calendar that shows different events for a given month. I am using [jQuery fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

I have a specific color for every day of the month.

For that, I'm using the following code:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var cellDate = date.format('D');
    cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate]);      
},
```

`json_backgrundColor[cellDate]` is an array that contains the specific color for each day. 
`cellDate` is an integer (1-end of the specific month (28/29/30/31)).

My problem is that the days of the previous month and the next month are also affected by it. They are getting colored according to the values of the specific month.

e.g: 
 - Day 29 of the previous month is getting the background color of the day 29 of the current month
 - Day 1 of the next month is getting the background color of the day 1 of the current month

See this picture:

[[image: Example month]

I want the background color of days from previous/next month will be white. (see the marked days in the picture attachted. they don't belong to the specific month and I want them to be with white background color)

Anybody knows how can I target them and do it?

Comment: Go check what classes those cells have, and if there is any difference between cells for days in the current vs other months.

Comment: i guess i should write in javascript 2 "if"s.

dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var cellDate = date.format('D');
    if ( date < firstDayOfCurrentMonth || date>lastDayOfCurrentMonth ){
      cell.css('background-color', white); 
     }else {
      cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate]); 
}
},
the problem is that i dont know how to write it in javascript. can anybody help?

Comment: No. One if, that checks the cells class.

Answer (score 1):

The cells that fall outside of the current month get the class `fc-other-month` - so all you need to do should be to check the class, and only work on the cell if it doesn’t have it:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
  if(!cell.hasClass('fc-other-month')) {
    cell.css('background-color', 'blue'); // or whatever
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This: 
.fc-other-month{
  background-color: red;
}`

Comment: thanks for the answer. but that does not work for me. the  "dayRender: function" in the javascript part is overwrting it.

Comment: $('td.fc-other-month').prop('disable', true);
$('td.fc-other-month').addClass('fc-state-disabled');

Comment: Check this one:  https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/hzq47kbg/2/

Comment: i guess i should write in javascript an if. e.g:

dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var cellDate = date.format('D');
    if ( date < firstDayOfCurrentMonth || date>lastDayOfCurrentMonth ){
      cell.css('background-color', white); 
     }else {
      cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate]); 
}
},
the problem is that i dont know how to write it in javascript. can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.fc-other-month{
```

background-color: red;
}

Click here[https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/hzq47kbg/][1]

Comment: You should stop with the "Try this" thing. Make sure you understand the question (comment if you don't, to ask for clarifications), make sure you come to a solution that works and then post that solution. Just guessing what the solution might be is not enough answer. While we're at it, be sure to correctly format your answers and to add a meaningful description on why your answer solves the OP's issue. And don't post more than one answer with the same solution. Take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!